# Prevent element from updating - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, updating

I select an element of the page:

```
$mainSection = $('#main');
```

then I add more Elements via AJAX into the `<div id="main"></div>` element. Next time I call `$mainSection`, the newly added elements are also in it. But I don't want that. I would like that the variable `$mainSection` only has the content in it from the initial rendering of the page. I can't find a way to prevent jQuery from updating.

---

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $mainSection = $('#main').clone(true);
```

Then I add new elements to #main and then I check if they get found via:

```
$foundElement = $($mainSection + ":not(:has(*)):not(script):contains('"+newlyAddedContent+"')");
```

On page load, they are not there. But after I add them, they get found.

I also tried:

```
$mainSection = $('#main').html();
$mainSection = $($mainSection);
```

didn't work also.

---

Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate my point:

http://jsfiddle.net/VEQ2E/2/

---

The problem is somewhere burried in this line:
               $foundElement = $($mainSection + ":not(:has(*)):not(script):contains('"+newlyAddedContent+"')");

It somehow always searches through the whole document, when I do it like this.

Comment: `$mainSection = $('#main').clone();` see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for details

Comment: Tried this one, didn't work

Comment: How did it not work? Can you show a jsfiddle?

Comment: clone works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/VEQ2E/

Comment: @urbz How can you be sure it's `<div>`?

Comment: @Radek > Because when I made the Edit these were not shown but will be shown inside a `code block`. So I did not add any content, simply made it visible.

Comment: @urbz Ah, I see :) Thanks for clarifying that. Markdown comparison is now my friend.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/VEQ2E/2/

Comment: @user3181141 Your $mainSection+":not..." doesn't make sense, I've posted an answer demonstrating what is going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was not that your clone was getting changed, but rather the selector you were using to try finding something within the clone. Your code was like this:

```
$($mainSection + ":not(:has(*)):not(script):contains('"+newlyAddedContent+"')");
```

Concatenating an object with a string will turn the object into a string, simply `"[object Object]"`, then your selector will just look at the `":not(:has..."`

Instead, you should use filter:

```
$foundElement = $mainClone.filter(":not(:has(*)):not(script):contains('world')");
```

This will now only look within your `$mainClone` for items matching that filter.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VEQ2E/6/)

Comment: If you could explain it in more details I would be so happy! I still don't get why my first approach didn't work.

Comment: @user3181141, do `console.log($mainSection + ":not(:has(*)):not(script):contains('"+newlyAddedContent+"')"`, you'll see that $mainSection gets turned into a string.

Comment: @user3181141, so your selection was basically this (no matter what elements were in $mainSelection): `$("[object Object]:not(:has(*)):not(script):contains('"+newlyAddedContent+"')")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.clone(true)`:

```
$mainSection = $('#main').clone(true);
```

It every time takes the `clone/copy` of the initial state of this div.

### *Note:*

```
.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )
```

#### withDataAndEvents : Boolean (default: false)

#### deepWithDataAndEvents : Boolean (default: value of withDataAndEvents)

A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work. Here is a jsFiddle to better illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/VEQ2E/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can take several approaches:

Cache the contents of `#main` before the update. This gives you just the contents of the element without the element.:

```
mainsectionContents = $('#main').html();
```

Or Cache a copy of `#main` before the update. This will give you the content together with the element, and depending on whatever else you may want to copy feel free to check the [**api docs**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
$mainsectionCopy = $('#main').clone();
```